# Validating Binary Search Tree - Beginner at Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

So essentially I want to start with a node, and it has to be greater than the left subtree but smaller than the right... and so on. On my worksheet it says to split it into two functions to make it easier. To use 'maybe a'. (It can't match up type 'maybe a' to 'a', which completely stops me.

This is what I have, I saw a similar question asked but couldn't really understand it properly. Thanks in advance.

```
is_valid_binary_search_tree :: Ord a => BSTree a -> Bool
is_valid_binary_search_tree tree = case tree of 
    Null                               -> True
    Node element t1 t2
        | element > get_element t1 -> is_valid_binary_search_tree t1
        | element < get_element t2 -> is_valid_binary_search_tree t2
        | otherwise                -> False 

get_element :: BSTree a -> Maybe a
get_element tree = case tree of
    Null               -> Nothing
    Node element t1 t2 -> Just element
```

It can compile but says in-exhaustive patterns in get_element if I remove Null -> Nothing.
The is_valid_binary_search_tree also doesn't compare if the subtree's right subtree is smaller than the main node. (Which is really my big issue)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your described solution is that it is *not* sufficient to simply check if the current tree element is larger than the left, respectively smaller than the right child. 
For example, the following is not a valid binary tree:

```
Node 3 (Node 1 (Node 0 Null Null) (Node 2 Null Null)) 
       (Node 10 (Node (-1) Null Null) (Node 12 Null Null))
```

Actually there's a simple solution: 
Do an in-order traversal of the tree (i.e. transform it into a list) and then check if the list is ascending:

```
inOrder Null = [] 
inOrder (Node a t1 t2) = inOrder t1 ++ [a] ++ inOrder t2
```

Comment: Thanks, I put it all together and got it.
I decided to write a Bool is_ordered function in the process and noticed that for it to check recursively if it was in ascending order, it didn't accept `x:xs = x <= is_ordered xs`
Rather: `x:y:zs = x <= y && is_ordered (y:zs)`
Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: @HerrSchlachter: `x` has type `a`, while `is_ordered xs` has type `Bool`. It makes no sense to compare them with `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

I built upon Peter's answer to provide a working solution

```
inOrder :: Tree a -> [a]
inOrder Nil = []
inOrder (Node y l r) = inOrder l ++ [y] ++ inOrder r

isAscending :: [Int] -> Bool
isAscending [x] = True
isAscending (x:xs) = x <= head (xs) && isAscending xs

is_valid_binary_search_tree :: Tree Int -> Bool
is_valid_binary_search_tree = isAscending . inOrder
```